# What is required for a LINQ query to work on an Azure Table?

Tags: c#, linq, azure

I am trying to use an Azure App Service back end for a mobile app I am writing.  I want to be able to query my table against something besides the Id.  This works:

```
IMobileServiceTable<NewSite> SiteTable = client.GetTable<NewSite>();

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        List<NewSite> items = await SiteTable
            .Where(i => i.Id == "2f2a098a-3b29-4d63-8c03-96869533c034")
            .ToListAsync();

        foreach (var site in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", site.Name, site.SiteID));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
});
```

When I try to query against a different field i.e. SiteID which is a string like this:

```
IMobileServiceTable<NewSite> SiteTable = client.GetTable<NewSite>();

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        List<NewSite> items = await SiteTable
            .Where(i => i.SiteID == "ChIJlx4_GaWaYogRs3NXTsPogTc")
            .ToListAsync();

        foreach (var site in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", site.Name, site.SiteID));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
});
```

I get the Error:

> DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed.  (Bad Request)

Is there something special that you have to do in order to query on different fields in the data table?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132371/ms-azure-bad-request-400) was some similar issue.

Comment: Is the GUID correct?

Comment: @jdweng both are strings even though the Id was derived from a Guid.

Comment: @Alex if I lowercase SiteID then it won't compile since my object has it in upper case.

Comment: Check out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743568/mobileserviceinvalidoperationexception-error-bad-request it seem similar too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the template provided in the example app, but this seems to have been the problem.  Once I removed the  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "siteid")], it allowed me to query on the field.  I'm not sure what the purpose it for this attribute, but it seems to work better without.

```
public partial class NewSite
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "siteid")]
    public string SiteID { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "note")]
    public string Note { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lat")]
    public double? Lat { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lng")]
    public double? Lng { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something special that you have to do in order to query on different fields in the data table?

According to your error message, it seems that your project didn’t load library well. Or the library version is not correct. You could  right click project>Manage Nuget Packages>reinstall the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client package to try again. I also find a similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/450), you could refer to.

And I have tested your code on my side, I could get the result even I add the **JsonProperty** attribute for the field.
[image]

> I'm not sure what the purpose it for this attribute, but it seems to work better without.

The **JsonProperty** Attribute is used to define the mapping between the PropertyName mapping between the client type and the table.  For example, if you change the property name of SiteID to 'siteid', then you get result like 'siteid=id1' instead of 'SiteID=id1'. For more details about this attribute, you could read this [article](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm).

Comment: I tried doing what you got to work, but it still didn't work for me.  It did work when I made the Json Attributes match the case of the property.  Once I did that, the query worked.